# Generate log file every hour even using log4j

Tags: log4j

***Requirement :***

To generate log file every hour with some header/content even if no logging is done i.e. there should be 24 log files.

---

***Issue:***

Log file is only getting generated when actual logging method/function is called. if there is no activity, no log file is getting generated.

---

***Implementation:***

log4j.xml

```
<appender name="TEST" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/testingApp/testing.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH'.log'"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="TESTING" additivity="false">
  <level value="warn"/>
  <appender-ref ref="TEST"/>
   </logger>
<root>
    <level value="warn"/>
    <appender-ref ref="TEST"/>
</root>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can make the logger write something without calling a log function. Why do you need one file per hour? Maybe you have a long-running process, so could make it heart beat - and write a "Still alive" message to the log files?

Comment: this is requirement from my client as they need file every hour. so we will be sending the file(with or without any log)doing I/O operation and archive the existing and create new. is there any way I can create separate log file every hour or any other way to achieve.